# What's the proper way to add a layout to a qtablewidget in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I've already asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319407/how-do-i-add-a-layout-to-a-qtablewidget-in-pyqt) but I'd like to know the proper way to add a layout to qtablewigets and also how could I put 2 table widgets in the same window, side by side if they both only had 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the tables them within a `QHBoxLayout`.

Code:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        QtGui.QTableWidget.setMinimumSize(self, 500, 500)
        QtGui.QTableWidget.setWindowTitle(self, "Custom table widget")
        self.table1 = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.configureTable(self.table1)

        self.table2 = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.configureTable(self.table2)

        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(self)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)

        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.table1)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.table2)

        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)

        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.close)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.close)

    def configureTable(self, table):
        rowf = 3
        table.setColumnCount(3)
        table.setRowCount(rowf)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("col1"))
        table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("col2"))
        table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("col3"))
        table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        # table.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Images:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Happy holidays and merry Christmas.

Comment: Might you be able to answer my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340061/how-can-i-connect-a-pages-function-to-a-qwizards-next-button